# if (err) throw err always shows process.nextTick(function){throw err;});

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm a noob when it comes to programming.  I am trying to understand Node.js and MongoDB.

Below is my code that will search a database and sort it by State (e.g. California, Hawaii, Vermont, etc.), and by Highest temperature.

When I run app.js, I always get this error:

> process.nextTick(function() { throw err; });
>                                    ^  MongoError: server localhost:27017 sockets closed  at Server.destroy
>   (D:...\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\mongodb- 
>   core\lib\topologies\server.js:664:47)

From my understanding, this is because the cursor has reached the end of the db, before my update() to the database has completed.  Please correct me if I am wrong.

How can I correct this issue?  If I comment out the *if (err) throw err;* that is directly under the db.collection.update() call, then there are no error messages(obviously), but I want to prevent the error in the first place so that I can use the if (err) throw err;

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/weather', function(err, db) {
if(err) throw err;

var cursor = db.collection('data').find().sort({"State" : 1, "Temperature" : -1});

    var newstate = "";
    var query = {};

    //console.log(docs);
    cursor.each(function (err, doc) {
        if (err) throw err;

        if (doc == null){
             return db.close();
        }

        if (newstate != doc.State) {
            //console.log("We are on State: " + doc.State + "\n");
            newstate = doc.State;
            query['_id'] = doc['_id'];
            //console.log("query id is "+query['_id'] + "\n")
            var operator = { '$set' : { 'month_high' : true } };
            db.collection('data').update(query, operator, function(err, updated) {
                if(err) throw err;
                console.dir("Successfully updated " + doc.State + " documents.");
                return; /*db.close();*/
            });
        }
        //db.close();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Throwing an error in async operations unless handled by a promise is not the correct away to handle the error if it occurs. Depending on your code you should be returning the error to the calling code or exiting script with process.exit.  I would use a console.error to print your error so you know what error you are hitting.